# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory, android-asynctask

```
        try {       
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            try
            {
                ((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).interactionResult = gson.fromJson(HomeCardString.toString(), InteractionSummaryResult.class);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("myyyy", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + responseString + "\"" + t.getMessage());
        }
```

gson.fromgson..... This line creating exception at `Throwable t ....`. The data which I have in `HomeCardString.toString()` is very big. about 1.9MB in a notepad file. I can't reduce the size of that data. What to do with that?

```
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at com.stalker.androidapp.InteractionTabFragment$ProfileInteractionCall.onPostExecute(InteractionTabFragment.java:175)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at com.stalker.androidapp.InteractionTabFragment$ProfileInteractionCall.onPostExecute(InteractionTabFragment.java:1)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
08-29 16:34:36.963: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why can't you reduce the size of the data? 1.9 MB for JSON data is...excessive, to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting `android:largeHeap="true"` for your application in the manifest. Here is the reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap

If this doesn't work, have a look at this post:

[JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file/9460267#9460267)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
        Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + responseString + "\"" + t.getMessage());
```

to

```
        String res = responseString.length() > 160 
            ? responseString.substring(0, 40) + "..." : responseString;
        Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + res + "\":\n" + t.getMessage());
```

as logging is not critical.

Comment: Thats helpful but I was in search of something Bruno has shared