# OutOfMemoryError while inserting data from large JSON file into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am reading a JSON file of roughly 6 GB using Java. The goal is to import all the JSON data into a MySQL database. The program runs fine for few initial records but then throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` with message *Java heap space error*. I am using the `JsonParser` class to read the file and using `nextToken()` to read the next JSON token. The system on which the program is running has 8 GB RAM.

How do I insert all the data into the the MySQL database from the JSON dataset?

Comment: I think the reason that you're getting the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is because the code is trying to parse the entire file at once. Look to see if the API you're using supports streaming, Which `JsonParser` class are you using? Most support streaming, have a look at the documentation.

Comment: @ Robert i am using  jsonparser class in jackson api

Comment: How much memory are you allocating to the Java Heap? Last I checked the defaults were no where *near* 6GB; if the hardware you're running on has only 8GB you're likely going to need to do something fancier than loading the whole thing into memory at once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434779/maximum-java-heap-size-of-a-32-bit-jvm-on-a-64-bit-os

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the system has 8 GB of RAM doesn't necessarily mean that the JVM can allocate that amount of memory. The total space the JVM depends on several factors, including operating system, Java configuration and JVM overhead.

I'm guessing that you are reading the file at once, which requires the JVM to allocate roughly 6 GB of memory in order to store all bytes into memory. The JVM fails to allocate that amount of memory and throws an `OutOfMemoryError`.

If the abovementioned assumption is correct, then you might want process the input stream instantly while reading it. [Jackson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) and [Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson) might do the job for you.

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file) has several answers which might be useful to read.
- [Javarevisited.blogspot.nl](http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2015/03/parsing-large-json-files-using-jackson.html) provides a tutorial to process the JSON file while reading it, using the Jackson Streaming API.

*More about the Java heap size: http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html.*