# TokenBuffer Jackson Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am wondering what to do about large files of JSON.

I don't want to store them in memory so I don't want to do `JsonNode`s because *I think* that stores the entire tree in memory.

My other idea was using `TokenBuffer`. However, I'm wondering how this works. Does the `TokenBuffer` store the entire document as well ? Is there a max limit. I know that it's a performance best practice but if I do:

```
TokenBuffer buff = jParser.readValueAs(TokenBuffer.class);
```

It seems like it reads the whole document at once (which I don't want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of [TokenBuffer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/TokenBuffer) is to store an extensible array of JSON tokens in memory. It does that by creating at first 1 `Segment` object with 16 `JsonToken` objects and then adding new `Segment` objects as needed.

You are correct to guess that the entire document will be loaded in memory. The only difference is that instead of storing an array of chars it stores the tokens. The performance advantages according to the [docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi):

1. You can reprocess JSON tokens without re-parsing JSON content from textual representation.
2. It's faster if you want to iterate over all tokens in the order they were appended in the buffer.

`TokenBuffer` is not a low level buffer of a disk file in memory.

I you only want to parse a file once without loading all of it at once in memory skip the `TokenBuffer`. Just `createJsonParser` from a `JsonFactory` or `MappingJsonFactory` and get tokens with `nextToken`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9390517/1413133).