# How to create a Java method to parse a big JSON file

Tags: java, json, parsing, iterator, jackson

I am trying to parse the content of [JSON file text.json](http://pastebin.com/W8AL2cAB) by using Jackson library.

What I want is to make a java method to get all keys and values of it, but so far in my code I get only the first key and the first value of the JSON file.

The code snippet I used as guidance to make my own Java class is the following:

```
public void parse(String json)  {
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);  

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
    while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
        System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
    }
}
```

And my Java class that I created is shown below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonStreamExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Create a JsonFactory instance
            JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

            //Create a JsonParser instance to read from file c:\\text.json
            JsonParser jParser = factory.createJsonParser(new File("c:\\text.json"));

            /*Create an ObjectMapper instance to provide a pointer
             * to root node of the tree after reading the JSON
             */
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);

            //Create tree from JSON
            JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jParser);  

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.getFields();
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
                System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
            }

            jParser.close();

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My Eclipse output is the following which creates only 1 pair(key-value):

```
Key: cells  Value:[{"type":"basic.Circle","size":{"width":90,"height":54},"position":{"x":-80,"y":200},"angle":0,"id":"cae4c219-c2cd-4a4b-b50c-0f269963ca24","embeds":"","z":1,"wi_name":"START","wi_displayName":"START","wi_description":"","wi_join":"<None>","wi_split":"<None>","wi_performingRole":"<None>","wi_expected_activity_time":null,"wi_expected_user_time":null,"wi_maximum_activity_time":null,"wi_initial_delay":null,"wi_time_unit":"Seconds","wi_required_transitions_for_AND_JOIN":null,"wi_custom_page":"","attrs":{"circle":{"fill":"#000000","width":50,"height":30,"stroke-width":1,"stroke-dasharray":"0"},"text":{"font-size":10,"text":"START","fill":"#ffffff","font-family":"Arial","stroke":"#000000","stroke-width":0,"font-weight":400}}},{"type":"basic.Circle","size":{"width":90,"height":54},"position":{"x":210,"y":200},"angle":0,"id":"d23133e0-e516-4f72-8127-292545d3d479","embeds":"","z":2,"wi_name":"END","wi_displayName":"END","wi_description":"","wi_join":"<None>","wi_split":"<None>","wi_performingRole":"<None>","wi_expected_activity_time":null,"wi_expected_user_time":null,"wi_maximum_activity_time":null,"wi_initial_delay":null,"wi_time_unit":"Seconds","wi_required_transitions_for_AND_JOIN":null,"wi_custom_page":"","attrs":{"circle":{"fill":"#000000","width":50,"height":30,"stroke-width":1,"stroke-dasharray":"0"},"text":{"font-size":10,"text":"END","fill":"#ffffff","font-family":"Arial","stroke":"#000000","stroke-width":0,"font-weight":400}}},{"type":"basic.Rect","position":{"x":-80,"y":370},"size":{"width":90,"height":54},"angle":0,"id":"a53898a5-c018-45c4-bd3f-4ea4d69f58ed","embeds":"","z":3,"wi_name":"ACTIVITY_1","wi_displayName":"ACTIVITY 1","wi_description":"","wi_join":"<None>","wi_split":"<None>","wi_performingRole":"<None>","wi_expected_activity_time":null,"wi_expected_user_time":null,"wi_maximum_activity_time":null,"wi_initial_delay":null,"wi_time_unit":"Seconds","wi_required_transitions_for_AND_JOIN":null,"wi_custom_page":"","attrs":{"rect":{"width":50,"height":30,"rx":2,"ry":2,"stroke-width":1,"stroke-dasharray":"0"},"text":{"text":"Activity","font-size":10,"font-family":"Arial","stroke":"#000000","stroke-width":0,"font-weight":400}}},{"type":"basic.Rect","position":{"x":220,"y":370},"size":{"width":90,"height":54},"angle":0,"id":"e2bd21f2-508d-44b9-9f68-e374d4fa87ea","embeds":"","z":4,"wi_name":"ACTIVITY_2","wi_displayName":"ACTIVITY 2","wi_description":"","wi_join":"<None>","wi_split":"<None>","wi_performingRole":"<None>","wi_expected_activity_time":null,"wi_expected_user_time":null,"wi_maximum_activity_time":null,"wi_initial_delay":null,"wi_time_unit":"Seconds","wi_required_transitions_for_AND_JOIN":null,"wi_custom_page":"","attrs":{"rect":{"width":50,"height":30,"rx":2,"ry":2,"stroke-width":1,"stroke-dasharray":"0"},"text":{"text":"Workitem","font-size":10,"font-family":"Arial","stroke":"#000000","stroke-width":0,"font-weight":400}}},{"type":"link","source":{"id":"cae4c219-c2cd-4a4b-b50c-0f269963ca24"},"target":{"id":"d23133e0-e516-4f72-8127-292545d3d479"},"router":{"name":"manhattan"},"labels":[{"position":0.5,"attrs":{"text":{"text":"Name"}}}],"id":"60ee7ff7-3a3b-487d-b581-49027e7bebe4","embeds":"","z":5,"attrs":{".marker-source":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z","transform":"scale(0.001)"},".marker-target":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z"},".connection":{"stroke":"black"}}},{"type":"link","source":{"id":"a53898a5-c018-45c4-bd3f-4ea4d69f58ed"},"target":{"id":"e2bd21f2-508d-44b9-9f68-e374d4fa87ea"},"router":{"name":"manhattan"},"labels":[{"position":0.5,"attrs":{"text":{"text":"Name"}}}],"id":"cea0d1c2-2c18-4bd7-ba35-d94918c6fc9b","embeds":"","z":6,"attrs":{".marker-source":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z","transform":"scale(0.001)"},".marker-target":{"d":"M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z"},".connection":{"stroke":"black"}}}]
```

I just need to make a method to put this code inside to get all key-value pairs:

```
//Create a JsonFactory instance
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

//Create a JsonParser instance to read from file c:\\text.json
JsonParser jParser = factory.createJsonParser(new File("c:\\text.json"));

/*Create an ObjectMapper instance to provide a pointer
 *to root node of the tree after reading the JSON
 */
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);

//Create tree from JSON
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jParser);  


Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.getFields();
while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
    System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
}
```

How will I do it please?

Comment: can you share the json? if not here, may be on pastebin or gist?

Comment: i meant the content of c:\\text.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file)

Comment: I don't want a Java code in which I have to write on my own all JSON keys and values. I want it to happen automatically.

That's the main difference comparing my problem to many other solutions for example JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file

Comment: @PavanKumar here is my JSON file http://pastebin.com/yvu0mHCR

Comment: @PavanKumar now I have a progress on the issue. Thanks to RobbyCornelissen who pointed out that I don't have a JSON object but a JSON array instead I have to change my code properly since so far I was parsing an array and treating it like an object . I will let you know. Thank you all.

Comment: I changed my code, my text.json and I improved my new question. Thank you all for your so far support. I am really close.

Comment: SO is no ordinary forum where one adds stuff like "[edited]" or "[solved]" into the title, so please stop doing that.

Comment: Thank you @Tom very much. I'll keep it in mind to be a better community contributor.

Comment: Thank you, that's nice to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing JSON library.

I used `json-simple-1.1.1`

My final code that worked is the following:

```
package jsontoxml;

import java.io.*;

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.*;
import java.util.*;


public class JacksonStreamExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
     try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("text.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONArray cells = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cells");
        Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = cells.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

     } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

     }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Jackson2 instead of Jackson1. As the error message specifies, Jackson1's `JsonNode` indeed does not have this `fields()` method, while [Jackson2's version does](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields()).

In Jackson1, you would have to do something like this:

```
Iterator<String> fieldNameIterator = rootNode.getFieldNames();

while (fieldNameIterator.hasNext()) {
    String fieldName = fieldNameIterator.next();
    JsonNode fieldValue = rootNode.getFieldValue(fieldName);

    System.out.println("Key: " + fieldName + "\tValue:" + fieldValue);
}
```

Comment: I changed my code and I incorporated yours. The error is removed but in console I see nothing. Please take a look in my edited code. Thank you very much. Keep in mind that I have the following warning: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method getFieldValue(String) from the type JsonNode is deprecated JacksonStreamExample.java /JsonToXML/src line 29 Java Problem

Comment: @user6681439: So the problem in your question was solved? If yes, you ought to accept the answer given. If fixing the problem meant you encountered a new one, you could ask a new question.

Comment: *The error is removed but in console I see nothing.* Makes sense. You're parsing an array and treating it like an object.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen you are perfectly right. That is why I was seeing nothing in console. I will fix it and I will let you know. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Henrik I changed my code, my text.json and I improved my new question. Thank you all for your so far support. I am really close.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have modified the question and json, here is the solution you're looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Map source = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(new File(
                "C:\\json.txt"), Map.class);

        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        buildFlattenedMap(result, source, null);
        for (String s : result.keySet()) {
             System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void buildFlattenedMap(Map<String, Object> result,
        Map<String, Object> source, String path) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : source.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (hasText(path)) {
            if (key.charAt(0) == '[') {
                key = StringUtils.join(path, key);
            } else {
                key = StringUtils.join(path, '.', key);
            }
        }
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof String) {
            result.put(key, value);
        } else if (value instanceof Map) {
            // Need a compound key
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) value;
            buildFlattenedMap(result, map, key);
        } else if (value instanceof Collection) {
            // Need a compound key
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Collection<Object> collection = (Collection<Object>) value;
            int count = 0;
            for (Object object : collection) {
                buildFlattenedMap(result, Collections.singletonMap("["
                        + (count++) + "]", object), key);
            }
        } else {
            result.put(key, value == null ? StringUtils.EMPTY : value);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean hasText(CharSequence str) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
        return false;
    }
    int strLen = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

FYI, buildFlattenedMap method is actually from spring framework which I had used recently for processing a similar stuff.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlProcessor.java