# getting field data on a large json url using java

Tags: java, arrays, json, url

i'm having trouble on a large size json and my script stock in buffered reader, is there's any tips to solve this.

this is the link of the json : [CLICK](http://mis.daprdp.net/json/data?table=sp_geotag_photo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file)