# GSON: Java out of memory error heap space

Tags: java, json, string, gson, android

I'm trying to convert a large object into json format as a string using the below code,I'm getting out of memory exception.However we are using heap size of 1GB.

```
gson.toJson(this);
```

How can we use gson streaming API(https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming)  to eliminate this error without increasing heap size ?

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)
        at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:112)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:576)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:417)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.write(TypeAdapters.java:426)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.write(TypeAdapters.java:410)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:640)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:595)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:575)
```

Comment: How bis is the object you're talking about? if the object's memory footprint is close to 1G, this might not be solvable with a different serialization approach.

Comment: Object has some properties and an arraylist which has 104219 records,each record has 5 properties.

Comment: @Ashok Are you sure you would like the result as a single big json? I recently converted ~50GB of data into json files, but I partitioned the data to multiple files, each were just a few MBs.

Comment: In order to get a full fledged example, please provide your *JSON* document structure and what you have already tried.

Comment: @tmarwen please find the structure here http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=67b451d0ec82b7e6ece4a1d768566012,the data property contains more than 100000 records.I have already mentioned the code I tried --> gson.toJson(this);

Comment: @appl3r I need it as a string containing json format

Comment: Dear downvoter,if you know the answer please let me know rather than downvoting !

Comment: I've encountered the same error. Can you tell what version of GSON you are using? My stacktrace is similar:
at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>()V (OutOfMemoryError.java:48)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf([CI)[C (Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(I)V (AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
... at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(Ljava/lang/Number;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter; (JsonWriter.java:534)

Answer (score 2):

You can read big Json files without loading the whole thing into memory, by using a streaming approach.

Even Gson supports Streaming: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html

Also: [JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file)

Comment: I'm actually trying to write to json format as a string

Comment: Oh, true, sorry. But the Stream API has Write mode too, and If you are already using the Gson Stream API to achieve this, I don't know what you would like to hear as an answer, because you did not post any additional code.

Comment: well on desktop it still requires a lot of memory even when using JsonReader (which expects input stream as input), e.g. I need to get some info from the next json file `instances_train2017.json` (448MB), you can find it in http://images.cocodataset.org/annotations/annotations_trainval2017.zip So on my PC with 6GB memory I get `memory out` exception