# How pass arguments to run method of RelationalDataAccessApplication Class

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am reading a geojson file and they can be very large, I think that the best option is to stream the geojson file and go logging it into the database with SQL manually.

Because it is not efficient with a JPA + Hibernate model, because it has many rows and even if it is lazy as soon as I remove the records it brings everything.

So I am following this:

- [JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file)
- https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

I'm using jdbc template: https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

My problems are:

- I don't know how to pass the name and inputStream parameters to the RelationalDataAccessApplication class from SchemeService
- I do not know how to get the name of the table because even if it is public it only allows me to access the run method.
- I don't know how to call the dropTable and readTable functions from SchemeService.

Here is my code of RelationalDataAccessApplication Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RelationalDataAccessApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RelationalDataAccessApplication.class);
    private String checkedNameTable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RelationalDataAccessApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        log.info("Deserialize GEOJSON");
        DeserializeJSONFileToPropsAndGeom.initialize(inputStream);
        List<String> properties = DeserializeJSONFileToPropsAndGeom.getProperties();
        List<String> geometries = DeserializeJSONFileToPropsAndGeom.getGeometries();

        log.info("CHECK IF TABLE EXISTS");
        checkedNameTable= nameTable("nombre pasado por el usuario");

        log.info("CREATING TABLE");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + checkedNameTable + " ( table_id SERIAL, properties jsonb not null, geom geometry(GeometryZ,4326), primary key (table_id));");

        log.info("INSERT DATA");
        for (int i=0; i<properties.size(); i++) {
            Object property = properties.get(i).toString().replace("'", "´");
            Object geometry = geometries.get(i);
            String SQL = "INSERT INTO " + checkedNameTable + " ( properties, geom ) VALUES ( '" + property + "', ST_Force3D(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('" + geometry + "'), 4326) ));";
            jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL);
        }
    }

    public String getCheckedNameTable() {
        return checkedNameTable;
    }

    private void dropTable(String nameTable) throws Exception {
        log.info("DROP TABLE " + nameTable);
        if (nameTable != null) {
            String SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + nameTable + ";";
            jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL);      
        }
    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> readTable(String nameTable) throws Exception {
        log.info("READ TABLE " + nameTable);
        if (nameTable != null) {
            String SQL = "SELECT table_id, CAST(properties AS text), GeometryType(geom) FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id ASC;";         
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String nameTable(String name) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        return (checkifExistTable(name)) ?
                name.toLowerCase() :
                name.toLowerCase() + "_" + uuid.toString().replace("-", "_");
    }

    private boolean checkifExistTable(String name) {
        String SQL = "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public'";
        boolean exists = false;
        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[] { "paramValue" }, Integer.class);
        exists = count > 0;
        return exists;
    }

}
```

Here is my code of SchemeService Class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SchemeService extends DaoCrudService {

    @Autowired
    private SchemeDao schemeDao;

    public <T> T createScheme(final String creatorId, final String name, final String description, final InputStream inputStream, final String attachmentId, final String filePath, final Class<T> targetVOClass) {
        Scheme scheme = createScheme(creatorId, name, description, inputStream, attachmentId, filePath);
        return getDozerService().map(scheme, targetVOClass);
    }

    protected Scheme createScheme(final String creatorId, final String name, final String description, final InputStream inputStream, final String attachmentId, final String filePath) {   

        RelationalDataAccessApplication.main(name, inputStream);
        String tableId = RelationalDataAccessApplication.getCheckedNameTable();

        Scheme scheme = new Scheme();
        scheme.setCreator(creatorId);
        scheme.setName(name);
        scheme.setDescription(description);
        scheme.setTableId(tableId);
        scheme.setAttachmentId(attachmentId);
        scheme.setFilePath(filePath);
        createScheme(scheme);

        return scheme;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> readTable(final String name) {
        return RelationalDataAccessApplication.readTable(name);
    }


    public void deleteScheme(final SchemeCriteria schemeCriteria) {
        SchemeVO scheme = read(schemeDao, schemeCriteria, SchemeVO.class);
        String nameTable = scheme.getTableId();
        // Call drop Table
        RelationalDataAccessApplication.dropTable(nameTable);
        delete(schemeDao, schemeCriteria);  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it!!

For this I have built a service which creates the table and inserts the data and also has the functions to read the table and delete it.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TableGeoJsonGenerator {

    private String checkedNameTable;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public String createTable(final String name, final InputStream inputStream) {
        DeserializeJSONFileToPropsAndGeom.initialize(inputStream);
        List<String> properties = DeserializeJSONFileToPropsAndGeom.getProperties();
        List<String> geometries = DeserializeJSONFileToPropsAndGeom.getGeometries();

        checkedNameTable= nameTable(name);

        jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + checkedNameTable + " ( table_id SERIAL, properties jsonb not null, geom geometry(GeometryZ,4326), primary key (table_id));");

        for (int i=0; i<properties.size(); i++) {
            Object property = properties.get(i).toString().replace("'", "´");
            Object geometry = geometries.get(i);
            String SQL = "INSERT INTO " + checkedNameTable + " ( properties, geom ) VALUES ( '" + property + "', ST_Force3D(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('" + geometry + "'), 4326) ));";
            jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL);
        }

        return checkedNameTable;
    }

    private String nameTable(String name) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        return (checkifExistTable(name)) ?
                name.toLowerCase() :
                name.toLowerCase() + "_" + uuid.toString().replace("-", "_");
    }

    private boolean checkifExistTable(String name)  {
        String SQL = "select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public' AND table_name LIKE '" + name + "'";
        boolean exists = false;
        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL, Integer.class);
        exists = count > 0;
        return exists;
    }

    public void dropTable(String nameTable) {
        if (nameTable != null) {
            String SQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + nameTable + ";";
            jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL);      
        }
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> readTable(String nameTable) {
        if (nameTable != null) {
            String SQL = "SELECT table_id, CAST(properties AS text), GeometryType(geom) FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id ASC;";         
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

SchemeService Class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SchemeService extends DaoCrudService {

    @Autowired
    private SchemeDao schemeDao;

    @Autowired
    TableGeoJsonGenerator table;

    public <T> T createScheme(final String creatorId, final String name, final String description, final InputStream inputStream, final String attachmentId, final String filePath, final Class<T> targetVOClass) {
        Scheme scheme = createScheme(creatorId, name, description, inputStream, attachmentId, filePath);
        return getDozerService().map(scheme, targetVOClass);
    }

    protected Scheme createScheme(final String creatorId, final String name, final String description, final InputStream inputStream, final String attachmentId, final String filePath) {   

        String tableId = table.createTable(name, inputStream);
        Scheme scheme = new Scheme();
        scheme.setCreator(creatorId);
        scheme.setName(name);
        scheme.setDescription(description);
        scheme.setTableId(tableId);
        scheme.setAttachmentId(attachmentId);
        scheme.setFilePath(filePath);
        createScheme(scheme);

        return scheme;
    }

    protected void createScheme(final Scheme scheme) {
        schemeDao.create(scheme);
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> readTable(final String name) {
        return table.readTable(name);
    }

    public void deleteScheme(final SchemeCriteria schemeCriteria) {
        SchemeVO scheme = read(schemeDao, schemeCriteria, SchemeVO.class);
        String nameTable = scheme.getTableId();
        // Call drop Table
        table.dropTable(nameTable);
        delete(schemeDao, schemeCriteria);  
    }

}
```