# Read REST api response hosting very large data

Tags: java, rest

I am calling an REST API endpoint which is hosting a very large amount of data. The data quantity is too much that my chrome tab crashes as well (It displays the data for a short time and it's loading even more data causing the tab to crash). Even postman fails to get the data and instead would only return 200 OK code without displaying any response body.

I'm trying to write a java program to consume the response from the API. Is there a way to consume the response without using a lot of memory?

Please let me know if the question is not clear. Thank you !!

Comment: What does “consume the response from the API” mean?  What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: @VGR It means make a GET call to the api, process the necessary fields which I need and store the result into my database.

Comment: And what is the type of the API response?  Is it XML?

Comment: The API that you use does it implement any of these techniques ? https://apievangelist.com/2018/04/20/delivering-large-api-responses-as-efficiently-as-possible/ or https://medium.com/@michalbogacz/streaming-large-data-sets-f86a53e43472

Comment: Example code (C and Ruby) for consuming from github REST API is in https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/ in paragraph Consuming the information

Comment: *Pagination* is most often used for this

Comment: Your question needs to be enhanced with details on the API you are consuming. 
Maybe the way you're using it led to such issues. 
To handle large number data, API generally implements one of those strategies:  
- Reduce Size Pagination
- Organizing Using Hypermedia
-  User Schema Filtering

Comment: @VGR It's JSON api response

Comment: @ralfhtp Yes I was expecting they do pagination but they don't. That would have really helped me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file)

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to use a *JSON streaming parser* like *Jackson Streaming API* (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi) for example code see https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/03/parsing-large-json-files-using-jackson.html

For JS there is https://github.com/DonutEspresso/big-json

Answer (score 1):

If data is really so large then better to split task:

1. Download full data via ordinary http client to disk
2. Make bulk processing , using some streaming approach, similar to SAX parsing for XML:
   [JAVA - Best approach to parse huge (extra large) JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file)

With such split, you will not deal with possible network errors during processing and will keep data consistency.