# How do I load the data into mysql where each line is a json?

Tags: java, mysql, json

I got a dataset where each line is in json format.

```
{"name":"alpha", "id":"111"}\n
{"name":"beta", "id":"222"}\n
...
```

But how do I load it into a mysql database? The dataset is quite large and it is impossible to parse it line by line in java.

Comment: You should use a streaming JSON parser so you don't load the entire file into memory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390368/java-best-approach-to-parse-huge-extra-large-json-file

Answer (score -1):

you can use 'mysql workbench' or 'mysqljsonimport'